# Custom PHP function for MySQL INSERT query

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a page, where I have multiple `SELECT` and `INSERT` functions in the same code, and decided to use a custom PHP function for both.
My functions are:

```
// MySQL SELECT statement
function sqlSelect($columns, $table, $condition){
    require("config.php");  
    $selectresult = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT " . $columns . " FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE " . $condition) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon)); 
    return $selectresult;
}

// MySQL INSERT statement
function sqlInsert($tble, $cols, $values){
    require("config.php");
    $insertquery = "INSER INTO `" . $tble . "` (" . $cols . ") VALUES (" . $values . ")";
    $insertresult = mysqli_query($dbcon, $insertquery) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
    return $insertresult;
}
```

The `sqlSelect()` works perfectly, but by `sqlInsert()` does NOT;
I call the function as below. Please tell me what's wrong in it.

```
sqlInsert(
        "users", 
        "f_id, user_uname, user_fname, user_lname, user_email, user_pass, user_deleted", 
        "'$f_id', '$user_name', '$user_first_name', '$user_last_name', '$user_email', '$user_password', 0"
    );
```

I tried the direct query, and it works like a charm:

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, "INSERT INTO `users` (f_id, user_uname, user_fname, user_lname, user_email, user_pass, user_deleted) VALUES ('$f_id', '$user_name', '$user_first_name', '$user_last_name', '$user_email', '$user_password', '0' )");
```

I get below error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSER INTO `users` (f_id, user_uname, user_fname, user_lname, user_email, user_p' at line 1

The list of columns is truncated for some reason by a character limit.

Comment: it is `INSER INTO` should be `INSERT INTO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo

> INSER INTO

should be

> INSERT INTO

Answer (score 0):

I find the difference in your code:
The last value is '0' not 0.

```
sqlInsert(
    "users", 
    "f_id, user_uname, user_fname, user_lname, user_email, user_pass, user_deleted", 
    "'$f_id', '$user_name', '$user_first_name', '$user_last_name', '$user_email', '$user_password', '0'"
);
```

For more details on investigation, please provide your error message to know exactly what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typos in the MySQL function which Mish pointed out.
Correct function is :

```
function sqlInsert($tble, $cols, $values){
    require("config.php");
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO `" . $tble . "` (" . $cols . ") VALUES (" . $values . ")";
    $insertresult = mysqli_query($dbcon, $insertquery) or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
    return $insertresult;
}
```

And call the function as:

```
sqlInsert(
        "users", 
        "f_id, user_uname, user_fname, user_lname, user_email, user_pass, user_deleted", 
        "'$f_id', '$user_name', '$user_first_name', '$user_last_name', '$user_email', '$user_password', 0"
);
```

Please feel free to use my function wherever required.
NOTE that this applies only when inserting a single row to a table.

You can use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to improve this function to add multiple rows in one INSERT query.